# ImageFound Activity Fails with Remote Desktop Minimized

Tags: rpa, uipath

Please pardon the image below. Long story.

[image]

Questions:

- Can the ImageFound Activity be used in this situation?
- If not, what are the best alternatives?
- When the pop-up window exists, maybe it is possible to receive an "ok, I'm ready!" message?

Thanks

Comment: And why not maximize remote desktop?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Since the bot runs within the Remote Desktop (RD) window, having the window maximized means the user cannot do other work on his computer. We want the user to be able to minimize the RD so he can do other work while the bot continues running within the RD.

Comment: Ok then try the setting ```PiP``` (Picture in Picture). That means the whole process runs in a sub window. That window can be minimized without trouble and you can work on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and dirtiest way to go around this is to have a RDP inside another RDP. This way you can keep the nested RDP maximized while the host RDP is minimized.